# Android ItemizedOverlay onTap information onto TextView

Tags: android, maps

i basically have a set of geopoints and i have them as ItemizedOverlays
Normally when you click on them an
Icon,
Title
Message (Snippet) Appears in the form of an AlertDialog Box

I wish to change this and when the onTap function is executed, i wish for the 
Icon
Title
Message to appear on a TextView just ontop of the map

Im guessing im missing something very simple but if anyone could please help i would be very grateful

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/locationInfo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:text="Choose a Flag!" />
```

MainActivity:

```
 GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint((int)(51.598707*1E6), (int)(-0.393416*1E6));
 OverlayItem overlayitem2 = new OverlayItem(point2, "Location 2" , "2A Pinner");
 itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem2);
```

ItemizedOverlay:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class NewItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
Context mContext;

public NewItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
}

public NewItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) 
{
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    mContext = context;
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay)
{
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mOverlays.size();
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
  OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);

  mOverlays.get(index).getTitle(); // i was messing around with this 
  mOverlays.get(index).getSnippet(); // and this lol


  AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
  dialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
  dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
  dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
  dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
  dialog.show();
  return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its ok i figured it out

Basically once i created the TextView in the main.xml

All i needed to do was reference the TextView by finding the view by id

and then simply:

```
viewName.setText(item.getTitle());
```

Simples ^^